# Парсинг txt файла через tokenizer

Tags: java, xml, dom

Есть список

```
1 Pinchuk Evhen.O 01-02-1992 02-01-2019
2 Ainchuk Evhen.O 02-02-1992 03-01-2019
3 Binchuk Evhen.O 03-02-1992 04-01-2019
4 Cinchuk Evhen.O 04-02-1992 05-01-2019
5 Dinchuk Evhen.O 05-02-1992 06-01-2019
```

Я его пытаюсь разбить токанайзером но получаю вместо одного значения - целый столбик.

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
        String line;
        String delimiter = " ";
        int linecounter=0;

      StringTokenizer tokenizer;
      BufferedReader input = null;
      try{
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) !=null){
          linecounter++;
          tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line,delimiter);
          while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()){

            String id = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String name = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String surname = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String dateBirthday = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String dateStartWorking = tokenizer.nextToken();
            System.out.println(id+name);
```

Делаю проверку на вывод в конце получаю столбец
А мне нужно внести данные в моей метод

```
List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();
            workers.add(new Worker(id,name,surname,dateBirthday,dateStartWorking));
            String fileName = "list.xml";
            writeToXML(workers,fileName);
```

в итоге вносит только последнюю строку

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Person xmlns="person">
  <Person id="5">
    <name xmlns="">Dinchuk</name>
    <surname xmlns="">Evhen.O</surname>
    <DateBirthday xmlns="">05-02-1992</DateBirthday>
    <DateStartWorking xmlns="">06-01-2019</DateStartWorking>
  </Person>
</Person>
```

Если вносить данные в ручную, то метод работает правильно и все вносит!

```
workers.add(new Worker("1","Papa","Papa","02-01-01192","02-01-1992"));
```

Помогите! Где я налажал ? Уже все перепробовал!

Comment: Как вариант - создайте сначала Document и рутовый элемент, затем читайте текстовый файл построчно и для каждой строки добавляйте к рутовому элементу новый элемент Person с дочерними элементами Name (туда пишете значение ФИО из текущей строки), BirthDate, и т.д.

Comment: @Sergi спасибо, пробую

Comment: @Sergi help please!

Comment: А у вас `writeToXML(workers,fileName);` внутри цикла что ли находится? :) т.е. на каждой итерации вы переписываете файл текущей строкой считанной из того txt

Comment: Приведите полный код, а то так не понятно. Похоже, что Вы просто для каждой строки перезаписываете xml файл

Comment: @gil9red о боже)спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полный код

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException, IOException {

        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        String file = "text.txt";

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
        String line;
        String delimiter = " ";


      StringTokenizer tokenizer;
      BufferedReader input = null;
      List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();
      String fileName = "list.xml";
      try{

        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) !=null){

          tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line,delimiter);

          while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()){

            String id = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String name = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String surname = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String dateBirthday = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String dateStartWorking = tokenizer.nextToken();
            System.out.println(id);

            //Добавлю элементы в список

            workers.add(new Worker(id,name,surname,dateBirthday,dateStartWorking));



          }
           writeToXML(workers,fileName);
        }
      }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file " + fstream);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to read from file " + fstream);
      }finally {

        try {
          if (input != null)
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("Unable to close file " + fstream);
        }
    }
   }

   private static void writeToXML(List<Worker> workers, String fileName) throws IOException{
     Document doc = new Document();
     doc.setRootElement( new Element("Person", Namespace.getNamespace("person")));
     for (Worker worker : workers){
       Element workerElement = new Element("Person", Namespace.getNamespace("person"));
       workerElement.setAttribute("id", String.valueOf(worker.getId()));
       workerElement.addContent(new Element("name").setText(worker.getName()));
       workerElement.addContent(new Element("surname").setText(worker.getSurname()));
       workerElement.addContent(new Element("DateBirthday").setText(worker.getDateBirthday()));
       workerElement.addContent(new Element("DateStartWorking").setText(worker.getDateStartWorking()));
       doc.getRootElement().addContent(workerElement);
     }
     XMLOutputter xmlWriter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
     xmlWriter.output(doc, new FileOutputStream(fileName));
   }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется или `writeToXML(workers,fileName);` нужно прямо над `}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {` поместить, т.е. после всех циклов